# How to resolve Visual Studio 2015 Dependency Issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am unable to add or update any NuGet packages in one particular project of mine. If I try to update any package I will see following error message in the output window:

> Attempting to gather dependencies information for package
>   'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.1.3.2' with respect to project
>   'myproject', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2' An error
>   occurred while retrieving package metadata for
>   'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.4.0.0' from source
>   'C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\myproject\packages'.
>   ========== Finished ==========

And when I build my project I see conflicts like this:

> There was a conflict between "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp,
>   Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" and
>   "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". 1>
>   "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" was chosen because it was primary and
>   "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" was not. 1>      References which
>   depend on "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, Version=1.2.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"

Does anybody know how I resolve this issue? Or do I have to recreate my project form scratch or something? I do not understand what the conflict is telling me to be able to work out how to fix it.

Comment: In your solution different projects uses different versions of same package. Try to update all packages for all projects to latest versions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but... my solution only has a single project?? any other ideas? no Packages will update. I'm getting very desperate as I cant seem to install any new Nuget packages and whilst my project seems to build ok and run I still see these conflicts.

Comment: Try vs -> tools -> options -> NuGet Package Manager -> General -> Clear Package Cache and restart your vs. Or try to add older nuget versions instead of the latest stable.